# htaccess redirect percentage sign

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, special-characters

i've got a problem with a htaccess-redirect and can't figured it out, after searching for nearly a hour. Please help me.

`RewriteRule ^yeah$ http://www.domain.de/awesome%123123 [NC,QSA,L,R=301]`

So i would like to redirect from: domain.de/yeah to domain.de/awesome%123123

But, the url is going to be cut after the %-sign.

Thanks a lot! I'm going to spend you a beer, if you ever visit Rostock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the RewriteRule flag B

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

RewriteRule ^yeah$ http://www.domain.de/awesome%123123 [B,NC,QSA,L,R=301]