# Redirect variable url with percentage character

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am currently working on my website where I've found some weird urls. I am trying to redirect (301) url's to the correct url but I cannot figured out how to correctly redirect those url's in .htaccess.

e.g. old url

```
/slug/variable-%language%.html
```

Al those urls should redirect to

```
/slug/variable-english.html
```

Where 'variable' can have different values (also with an '-' separator included.

Many thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314610/htaccess-redirect-percentage-sign please refer

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Redirect 301  /slug/variable-english.html  http://www.domain.com/slug/variable-english.html
Redirect 301  /slug/variable-chinese.html  http://www.domain.com/slug/variable-chinese.html
```

Why can you not just redirect to new domain as the rest of the urls is the same?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example-old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example-new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: around 100 redirects :)

Comment: The only change is the domain name right as old ones were: slug/variable-language and new are also slug/variable-language. So just use the rewrite rule above

Comment: No, it is not about a new domain. There is a variable %language% picked up by the google bot. The variable supposed to be filled in with the language set through application level, this didn't happend so that's why this %language% parameter in the url